# Cleanest way to dispose of Single subscriptions

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using RxHttpClient to make requests and return Single using .firstOrError(). I then subscribe to it to get the result. In order to dispose of that subscription, I used a CompositeDisposable like in the example below.

Is there some other way to do this that doesn't require so much boilerplate? Do I need to do this at all in the current situation?

This code is in an API that needs to make a request to another API to validate some data.

```
single = httpClient.retrieve(HttpRequest.POST("/endpoint", request), ResultDto.class)
                    .firstOrError()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())

CompositeDisposable cd = new CompositeDisposable();
Disposable d = single.subscribe(result -> {
                // ...
                cd.dispose();
            }, error -> {
                cd.dispose();
            });
cd.add(d);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much all of this is necessary, assuming you don't actually create `CompositeDisposable` like that and then throw it away.

You can save `cd.add(d);` and perhaps `Disposable d=` with RxJava 3 if you supply `cd` as the third parameter to [`subscribe`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Single.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.rxjava3.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.rxjava3.disposables.DisposableContainer-).

Comment: What do you mean by throwing away the CompositeDisposable? I use it to call dispose once I get a response to the request or an error. I don't see any other need for it.

Comment: "I use it to call dispose once I get a response [..] or an error" <- that is pointless. A `CompositeDisposable` is supposed to be hosted by a parent Activity where you clear it in `onPause` or `onDestroy` to stop any operation if the user navigates away.

Comment: This is not for Android, it's a server application. So I'm guessing it's not pointless in my case.

Comment: It is pointless. Nothing else sees that composite and disposing it like that is a no-op.

Comment: Right, so I don't need to call dispose at all then?

Comment: You don't need to call dispose like that. If you don't want to stop the network call from somewhere else, you don't need the composite either.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I wasn't completely clear on.